# How to express "A is B" in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I would like to write "A is B" in first order logic. For example "Apple is food". Here are my guesses:

$\exists x, s.t. \forall y, \mbox{food(x) & apple(y) & y} \in x.$

or simply

$food(apple)$

What is the proper expression?

Comment: I suppose you want to say something like "$A$ has property $B$".
Here we can view $B$ as a function which takes some input $A$ and gives true or false as output.
Then $B(A)$ says exactly that $A$ has property $B$.

Comment: First order logic doesn't allow two different "types" in some sense, so there is no such think as $y\in x$ in first order logic. Rather, you could write it as: $$\forall x:\text{apple}(x)\implies \text{food}(x).$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, but do you think `food(apple)` also appropriate?

Comment: No, $\text{food}(\text{apple})$ does not make sense, unless you can only talk about one apple.

Comment: See [Categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) (whose origin is with Aristotle) : "a proposition that asserts or denies that all or some of the members of one category (the *subject* term) are included in another (the *predicate* term)." Thus, with "Apple is food" you are asserting that the "category" *apple* is included in the category *food*. This mean (reading "category" as *set* or *class*) : "All apples are food".